# About an exception when I try to show a timestamp from a DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, parquet

i have to generate a parquet file from a csv file, and the parquet file need to have two columns, filename and creation date, so I have to load the csv file, create a DataFrame from it and add it two new columns before I use spark-csv to generate the parquet files.

This is my actual code:

```
def loadCSV(sqlContext : SQLContext, pathCSV: String, separator: String, haveSchema: String): DataFrame = {

//logger.info("loadCSV. header is " + haveSchema.toString + ", inferSchema is true, pathCSV is " + pathCSV + " separator is " + separator)
sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", haveSchema) // Use first line of all files as header
  .option("delimiter", separator)
  .option("nullValue","")
  .option("mode","FAILFAST")
  .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
  .load(pathCSV)

}

def writeDataFrame2Parquet(df: DataFrame, pathParquet: String, saveMode: SaveMode,header: String,delimiter:String): Unit = {

df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", header)
  .option("delimiter",delimiter)
  .option("nullValue","")
  .mode(saveMode)
  //by default, gzip. Another values are uncompressed, snappy, gzip, lzo. This can be changed only at sqlContext Level.
  //Configuration of Parquet can be done using the setConf method on SQLContext or by running SET key=value commands using SQL.
  //.option("codec","spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec" + compression_codec)
  .parquet(pathParquet)
}

@Test
def testAddNewFieldsToDataFrame () : Unit = {

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

implicit val sqlContext = CSVtoParquetTest.sql

val pathWrite = "src/test/resources/writefileWithNewField2.parquet"

val df: DataFrame = CSVtoParquet.loadCSV(sqlContext , pathCSVWithHeader, ";", "true")

df.show()

val newDFWithName = df.withColumn("generated-parquet-file",lit("my-generated-parquet-file"))
newDFWithName.show()

val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
//esto es un String, tienes que crear un java.sql.Timestamp partiendo de esta cadena.
val reportDate = dateFormat.format(now)

val generatedAt = lit(new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(reportDate).getTime))
println("generatedAt is " + generatedAt )
val newDFWithNameAndDate = newDFWithName.withColumn("generated_at",generatedAt )
newDFWithNameAndDate.show()

val saveMode = SaveMode.Overwrite
//writeDataFrame2Parquet(df: DataFrame, pathParquet: String, saveMode: SaveMode,header: String,delimiter:String):
CSVtoParquet.writeDataFrame2Parquet(newDFWithNameAndDate , pathWrite, saveMode,"true",",")

//ahora necesito cargar el DataFrame o cargar el fichero parquet recien generado para comprobar que efectivamente hay dos nuevos campos.

val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet(pathWrite)

parquetFile.registerTempTable("FINAL")

//busco uno de los campos recien creados
val distinctCountGeneratedDates = sqlContext.sql("SELECT distinct count(generated_at) FROM FINAL").collect()

Assert.assertNotNull("cannot be null!", distinctCountGeneratedDates )
println("distinctCountGeneratedDates.length is " + distinctCountGeneratedDates.length)
Assert.assertTrue(distinctCountGeneratedDates.length > 0)

val generatedDates = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM FINAL").collect()
Assert.assertNotNull("cannot be null",generatedDates)
Assert.assertTrue(generatedDates.length > 0)
generatedDates.foreach(println)
println("Done!")

}
```

The test runs fine, but, when i run the code in local mode and generate the parquet file and copied into my SPARK_HOME folder, I run this commands:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("my_parquet_folder")
## this command break the running!
parquetFile.show

scala> parquetFile.printSchema
root
|-- symbol: string (nullable = true)
|-- longname: string (nullable = true)
|-- ticker: string (nullable = true)
|-- equity_ticker: string (nullable = true)
|-- weight: string (nullable = true)
|-- id_isin: string (nullable = true)
|-- parquetFilename: string (nullable = true)
|-- generated_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Timestamps (with nanoseconds) are expected to be stored in 12-byte long binaries, but got a 19-byte binary.
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystRowConverter$$anon$3.addBinary(CatalystRowConverter.scala:269)
at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl$2$6.writeValue(ColumnReaderImpl.java:318)
at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.writeCurrentValueToConverter(ColumnReaderImpl.java:365)
at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.read(RecordReaderImplementation.java:405)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:209)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:201)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:168)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1839)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1839)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I do not understand why this code works in the unit test, but when I run the code in local (and cluster) mode, the timestamp is not been showed fine.

How can a i generate correctly this TimeStamp as a metadata generated field within the parquet file, what do i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I had to cast the timestamp as TimeStampType. this is the code, probably it is not the most optimal, but it works.

```
val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

  val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  val reportDate = dateFormat.format(now)

  val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000

  val generatedAt = lit(new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(reportDate).getTime))
  println("generatedAt is " + generatedAt )

  var newDFWithNameAndDate : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = null

  if (metadataCreationName == ""){
    println("ATTENTION! mra.generate.metadata.name should not be empty as parameter or as setting in the property file. Applying default name, parquetFilename!")
    newDFWithNameAndDate = newDFWithName.withColumn("generated_at",generatedAt )
  }else {
    newDFWithNameAndDate = newDFWithName.withColumn(metadataCreationName ,generatedAt )
  }

  val schema : StructType = newDFWithNameAndDate.schema
  println("schema is " + schema)
  val listFromSchema : List[StructField] = schema.toList

  val aSeq = mutable.MutableList[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]()

  val elementsType : StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()

  val numElements = listFromSchema.size
  var cont = 1
  //this part need to be optimized!
  for (elementFromSchema <- listFromSchema.reverse){
    println("elementFromSchema is " + elementFromSchema + ". name: " + elementFromSchema.name + ". dataType: " + elementFromSchema.dataType)
    val aColumn : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = new org.apache.spark.sql.Column(elementFromSchema.name)
    println("aColumn is " + aColumn)
    aSeq += aColumn
    val elementDataType = elementFromSchema.dataType
    println(elementDataType)
    val myElement = elementDataType match {
      case TimestampType => "timestamp"
      case StringType => "string"
      case IntegerType => "integer"
    }
    elementsType.append(myElement)
    if (cont<numElements) {
      elementsType.append(";")
      cont+=1
    }
  }//for
  println("elementsType is " + elementsType.toString())
  var df1 = newDFWithNameAndDate.select(aSeq:_*)

  df1 =  CSVtoParquet.castingDataFrame(df1, elementsType.toString(), CSVtoParquet.mapString2DataType)

  df1.show()

  writeDataFrame2Parquet(df1 , path_output_parquet, saveMode,header,separator)


def castingDataFrame(df: DataFrame, typeString: String, mapString2DataType: Map[String, DataType]): DataFrame = {

val arrayDataTypes: Array[DataType] = typeString split ";" map { name => mapString2DataType.getOrElse(name, StringType) }

val xprs = df.columns zip arrayDataTypes map { pairType => df.col(pairType._1) cast pairType._2 as pairType._1 }

df.select(xprs: _*)

}


def writeDataFrame2Parquet(df: DataFrame, pathParquet: String, saveMode: SaveMode,header: String,delimiter:String): Unit = {
logger.info("writeDataFrame2Parquet header is " + header
  +" saveMode is " + saveMode
  + " pathParquet is " + pathParquet
  + " delimiter is " + delimiter
)
df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", header)
  .option("delimiter",delimiter)
  .option("nullValue","")
  .mode(saveMode)
  //by default, gzip. Another values are uncompressed, snappy, gzip, lzo. This can be changed only at sqlContext Level.
  //Configuration of Parquet can be done using the setConf method on SQLContext or by running SET key=value commands using SQL.
  //.option("codec","spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec" + compression_codec)
  .parquet(pathParquet)
}
```

With this code, you can generate a parquet file with two extra metadata fields like the parquet generated filename and the creation date:

```
scala> val parquetFileDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("componentes_indices_comma_output7")
parquetFileDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [createdAt1: timestamp, fieldName1: string, id_isin: string, weight: string, equity_ticker: string, ticker: string, longname: string, symbol: string]

scala> parquetFileDF show false
16/12/01 16:59:20 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl

|createdAt1           |fieldName1                                                                                              |id_isin     |weight   |equity_ticker|ticker   |longname                    |symbol          |
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0010310956|1,589563 |SALM NO      |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0003028904|2,367745 |SCHA NO      |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0010736879|2,513974 |SCHB NO      |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|BMG7945E1057|0,444097 |SDRL NO      |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0003053605|2,276359 |STB NO       |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0010096985|19,105393|STL NO       |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|LU0075646355|2,947026 |SUBC NO      |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0010063308|12,973417|TEL NO       |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0003078800|1,964136 |TGS NO       |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|NO0010208051|6,068747 |YAR NO       |OBX Index|BB - IDX - KINGDOM OF NORWAY|BB,2000000205203|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|US00846U1016|         |A UN         |RIY Index|RIY Index                   |BB,2001000008410|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|US0138721065|         |AA UN        |RIY Index|RIY Index                   |BB,2001000008410|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|US02376R1023|         |AAL UW       |RIY Index|RIY Index                   |BB,2001000008410|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|US00751Y1064|         |AAP UN       |RIY Index|RIY Index                   |BB,2001000008410|
|2016-12-01 16:59:06.0|/Users/aisidoro/Desktop/mra-csv-converter/csvpruebacsvconverter/componentes_indices_comma_output7|US0378331005|         |AAPL UW      |RIY Index|RIY Index                   |BB,2001000008410|
...
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------+---------+----------------------------+----------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```